# SQL query generated by django F expression

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-orm

Does anyone know the actual query generated by django when you use F expression?

What will the generated query be for the example mentioned in the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

```
from django.db.models import F

reporter = Reporters.objects.get(name='Tintin')
reporter.stories_filed = F('stories_filed') + 1
reporter.save()
```

I tried viewing the query generated using:

```
from django.db import connection
logging.info('[----- DEBUG -----] Query -1: %s', connection.queries[-1])
logging.info('[----- DEBUG -----] Query -2: %s', connection.queries[-2])
logging.info('[----- DEBUG -----] Query -3: %s', connection.queries[-3])
```

but I don't see any query on the my model/table.

Anyone know how to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The query should be there in `connection.queries` - I just tested found it in there. The query sent to the database looks something like this for MySQL and Postgresql:

```
UPDATE "myapp_reporters" 
SET "stories_filed" = ("myapp_reporters"."stories_filed" + 1) 
WHERE "myapp_reporters"."id" = 123
```